# Can I change the VITE BUILD to create a common JS file instead of module?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I'm using VITE + REACT + TYPESCRIPT to create an web app, the build works fine but I noticed the build file was create as type="module", which needs node integration.

When I use react-scripts, the build is a single non-module JS file.

There is a way to make VITE builds as common js file instead of module? I tried to search on docs and GitHub but didnt find any answer.

The problem of using react-scripts for build is I need to change the folder and files to run "dev" with vite and "build" with react, which makes more difficult to maintain.

EDIT:

For more information i'm using  `"build": "tsc && vite build"` in the package.json file.

Which gives me the following file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-0dff223d.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-04490b11.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see the `type="module"` in script tag, there is a way to build the JS file as common JS without module? What i'm doing to fix it is to change the build script back to react-scripts lib. But it means I need to create public folder with index.js script.

Comment: did you find an answer to this...

Comment: @user3768258 sadly, not. I had to use react-scripts for build instead of vite, which makes the dependencies and packages bigger.